# What polyfills are needed from polyfill.io to run Blazor in IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, blazor, blazor-server-side, polyfills, blazor-client-side

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.1) point to [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/) to allow Blazor to run in IE 11.

All searching for an answer to this question lead me to [Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill](https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill). However, for licensing reasons, we are not allowed to use this solution.

So my question is: what polyfills are needed from the [polyfill.io builder](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/) to run Blazor in IE 11?

Comment: You could try to add [the polyfills](https://github.com/Daddoon/Blazor.Polyfill#about) the project using internally to see if it works. If you don't use the Blazor.Polyfill then I think you might need to add polyfills accordingly. Check if there's any error in IE 11 and add the polyfills according to the errors. You could also refer to [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9436#issuecomment-486797226) to see if it helps.

Comment: so you want to keep support for 3.7% of the usage market?

Comment: @Yu Zhou: I looked into that option as well. Those projects are very well run and supported especially core-js. My concern is with getting past licensing. Looking at Blazor.Polyfill, it is basically a wrapper around those 3rd party polyfills with webpack for tree shaking.

Comment: I can't find any other solutions than Blazor.Polyfill and there's no Microsoft official solution available. So I can only suggest you that polyfill.

Comment: Here is what the Blazor team told me: "... thanks for contacting us.

We don't have a specific list of polyfills we recommend. We suggest you look at the different community solutions and pick the one that works best for you." So I am going to use Blazor.PolyFill's webpack and try to match it wih polyfill.io builder to hopefully get a working solution. I am going to close this.

Comment: The Blazor team at Microsoft responded to me with an answer which makes my question here pointless. I should have chosen a different approach to begin with since all elements are on github.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support browsers that don't have WebAssembly support, such as IE11 then Blazor Server-side is the best option.

If you are going down a polyfill route you won't get support from the ASP.NET team and it may not work very well. I think the Blazor team tried polyfills early on and dropped support for them because of too many issues.

If you write your Blazor components correctly they will work on both server and client side - there are examples of hybrid clients out there that can switch between server and wasm versions, e.g. https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-hybrid-application-experimental/

Comment: You make a really good point about a lack of support and the likely reason for it.